# Best XPath practices for extracting data from a field that varies in format

Tags: python, xpath, lxml.html

I was using Python 3.8, XPath and Scrapy where things just seemed to work.  I took my XPath expressions for granted.

Now I'm must using Python 3.8, XPath and lxml.html and things are much less forgiving.  For example, using this [URL](https://www.yellowpages.com/nationwide/mip/toxglobal-diagnostics-llc-556885209?lid=1002050417627) and this XPath:

```
//dt[text()='Services/Products']/following-sibling::dd[1]
```

I would return a paragraph or a list depending on what the innerhtml was.  This is how I am attempting to extract the text now:

```
data = response.text
tree = html.fromstring(data)
Services_Product = tree.xpath("//dt[text()='Services/Products']/following-sibling::dd[1]")
```

which returns this:  Services_Product[]
which is a list of "li" elements for his page, but other times this field can be any of these:

```
<dd>some text</dd>
or
<dd><p>some text</p></dd>
or
<dd>
  <ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
  </ul>
</dd>
or
<dd>
  <ul>
    <li><p>some text</p></li>
    <li><p>some text</p></li>
  </ul>
</dd>
```

What is the best practice for extracting text from situations like this where the target field can be a number of different things?

I used this test code to see what my options are:

```
file = open('html_01.txt', 'r')
data = file.read()
tree = html.fromstring(data)
Services_Product = tree.xpath("//dt[text()='Services/Products']/following-sibling::dd[1]")
stuff = Services_Product[0].xpath("//li")
for elem in stuff:
    print(elem[0][0].text)
```

That returned this:
Health
Health
doctors
Health
doctors

Which is not correct.  Here's a screenshot of it in google chrome:
[The Xpath tool in google chrome along with the html in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Lz2.png)

Whats the best way to scrape this data using Python and Xpath - or other options?
Thank you.

Comment: Best practice is what gives you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours googling and then writing this post above, it just came to me:
old code:

```
Services_Product = tree.xpath("//dt[text()='Services/Products']/following-sibling::dd[1]")
stuff = Services_Product[0].xpath("//li")
```

and new code that returns a nice list of text:

```
Services_Product = tree.xpath("//dt[text()='Services/Products']/following-sibling::dd[1]")
stuff = Services_Product[0].xpath("//li/text()")
```

add the "/text()" on the end fixed it.